# Save edited inline text from CKEditor 4 asp net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

I am trying to implement [CKEditor 4](http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4-beta) into an ASP NET website that I am working on, but I cannot figure out how I would save the edited material from the [inline editor](http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/3528/samples/inlineall.html) I know how to do it with the the old version, but I just don't understand the process for this.

I have looked in the forums... There is not v4 forum.

I looked <strike>in</strike> for the documentation.... Couldn't find it.

I have a feeling that this is a simple task, but I just don't know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get your data with `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData()`. Then you can send it via AJAX or store it as a value of some input field. To do this periodically, follow this method:

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable' );

var savedData, newData;
function saveEditorData() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        newData = editor.getData();

        if ( newData !== savedData ) {
            savedData = newData;

            // Send it with jQuery Ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: 'yourUrl',
                data: savedData
            });

            // Or store it anywhere...
            // ...
            // ...
        }

        saveEditorData();
    }, 500 );
};

// Start observing the data.
saveEditorData();
```

You can also observe the [submit event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) and update some (hidden) form field with your data.

Have fun!

Comment: Awesome! Two great ways to start saving my data, in one answer! Who could ask for more!

Comment: This is a terrible answer. Polling for data getting changed is absolutely not the way Javascript should react to things. That's what events are for. You did mention "observing the submit event", but that makes your code make assumptions about the context in which the editor lives. Luckily the CKEDITOR class supports an event handling mechanism ( http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.event ) and does trigger a number of events to observe.

Comment: @TommiForsström The approach depends on what kind of implementation is required. Adam didn't mention what kind of app is he developing so we cannot assume this is wrong. He might need to save editor snapshots frequently for "draft backup" like in Gmail or similar, doesn't he? Hm?

The problem is that **CKEditor doesn't support content changed** event. This a very complex thing and will be supported in 4.1. See: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9794 At the moment there's no simple and safe way (event) to determine whether editor content changed since there are so many ways to modify it.

Comment: Interval polling based solutions in an event driven asynchronous environment are always flat-out wrong. Yes, there's no change event for CKEditor, but there is a key event and several other events you can use to latch onto changes.

Comment: Furthermore, there is an onchange plugin for CKEditor 4, but even that is kind of broken as the event observers are not properly scoped, so your editor object will get notified of ALL dom mutations. But if you're aware of this and protect against it, you'll be golden: http://ckeditor.com/addon/onchange

Comment: Another way to go around this is adding click / keyup handlers to the wrapping element of the editor. The events in the editor will bubble through and you can just respond to them. Whatever the correct answer is to the original post, setTimeout based polling should never ever be it. That's just a sure way of bleeding some memory, running into weird concurrency errors and depleting your stack. setTimeout is a horrible idea at least 99.99% of the time. Usually even more often.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get it with AJAX or send with a form? The value of for example the top right inline editor area with *Lorem Ipsum* can be gotten like in the older version with simply

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData().
```

In the [XHTML output example](http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/latest/ckeditor/samples/outputxhtml.html) they have a simple form that seems to work and I believe that using an (static) inline editor is just the same.

If you transform elements into editors inline dynamically, I would try to bind to the submit event and before submitting loop through all `CKEDITOR.instances`, get their data into hidden from fields. As for the hidden field naming or identifying which hidden field corresponds to which dynamic editor you'll have to figure out yourself :)